# Magento : From where the html of "<?php echo $_menu ?>" comes from?

Tags: magento

In magento page/html/topmenu.html file produce the menu items (ie category created in the backend)
Im styling those menus with twitter bootstrap css framenwork.
and it produces the menu items with

```
<ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
</ul>
```

Where can I edit the `<li>` tags classes produced by the `<?php echo $_menu ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top menu is one of the few areas where the HTML is generated inside of a block class.

The exact file is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`.

Look for the `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` method in this file which produces the majority of the HTML for the menu.

To add a new class for **all** of the menu items, you can override this block and modify the method.

1. Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`
2. Look for the following code (inside of the `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` function)

   ```
   if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
   }
   ```
3. After this, add the following:

   ```
   $classes[] = 'mynewclass';
   ```
4. Save the file, and refresh all of your Magento caches.

Comment: it is not good practice to override a class by copying the file into local code pool: the override should be done inside a module. edit your answer and you'll have my vote :)

Comment: It's not good practice to hack the core file and not override it at all.  I've given a straightforward solution to the problem.  Outlining how to develop an extension would be going beyond the initial problem the user is facing.  There are several articles already outlining how to develop and implement extensions;  I'll leave it to the individual to decide what is good practice for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Magenta development and after reading this q&a it took me a while to find out where to find the right file which is responsible for the shape of the top menu because at least in the current version (1.7.0.2) it isn't `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`. Instead it is `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/TopMenu.php`. Inside the file and inside the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` there is a `_getHTML()` method which you can change as you want.